# How to do update the database through the browser? DJANGO

Tags: python, html, django

I've successfully completed the ADDING stage, however I'm really stuck on the EDITING stage. This feature will allow the admin to change the details of a particular member through the browser. Any ideas? This is what I have done for the ADDING, but none for the editing.

**Views**

```
def edit_member(request, member_id):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    members = get_object_or_404(Member, id=member_id)
    form = MemberForm(request.POST or None, instance=member)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        else:
            form = MemberForm() 

    return render_to_response("templates/MemberUpdate.html",
        {'members': members, 'form':form}, 
    context)
```

**Forms.py**

```
class MemberForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Member
```

**MemberAdd.html**

```
{% for member in members %}
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ member.name}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
{% endfor %}

<p><h1>Add new members</h1></p>
<table>
<form action="" method="post">
    <tr>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
</tr>
    <input type="submit" value = "Submit" />
</form>
```

Traceback:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 1.7.3
Python Version: 3.2.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'chess',
 'member')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/naveed/my_py3/lib/python3.2/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  98.                 resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "/home/naveed/my_py3/lib/python3.2/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  343.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/home/naveed/my_py3/lib/python3.2/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  372.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/home/naveed/my_py3/lib/python3.2/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  366.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/usr/lib/python3.2/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
  124.     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "/usr/lib/python3.2/importlib/_bootstrap.py" in _gcd_import
  821.                     loader.load_module(name)
File "/usr/lib/python3.2/importlib/_bootstrap.py" in load_module
  436.         return self._load_module(fullname)
File "/usr/lib/python3.2/importlib/_bootstrap.py" in decorated
  141.             return fxn(self, module, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3.2/importlib/_bootstrap.py" in _load_module
  342.         exec(code_object, module.__dict__)
File "/home/naveed/my_py3/chess/chess/urls.py" in <module>
  3. from member import views
File "/usr/lib/python3.2/importlib/_bootstrap.py" in load_module
  436.         return self._load_module(fullname)
File "/usr/lib/python3.2/importlib/_bootstrap.py" in decorated
  141.             return fxn(self, module, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3.2/importlib/_bootstrap.py" in _load_module
  330.         code_object = self.get_code(name)
File "/usr/lib/python3.2/importlib/_bootstrap.py" in get_code
  413.                                 dont_inherit=True)

Exception Type: SystemError at /
Exception Value: ../Objects/tupleobject.c:126: bad argument to internal function
```

**Urls.py**

```
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'profile', views.profile, name='profile'),
url(r'leaderboard', views.leaderboard, name='leaderboard'),
url(r'MemberForm', views.Form, name='MemberForm'),
url(r'MemberUpdate', views.MemberUpdate, name='MemberUpdate'),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

Comment: Why are you duplicating all of the work of the ModelForm in the view by assigning the member properties from `cleaned_data` ? The ModelForm knows how to persist a Member by simply calling `form.save()` Also, what version of Django are you using? your view code is fairly antiquated

Comment: @Brandon I'm using Django 1.7.3 Should I take our cleaned_data? I followed a tutorial you see

Comment: That tutorial must have been very old. I'll add an answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're wanting to edit a specific `Member` instance, you need to retrieve the instance from the database, then pass it to your `ModelForm`:

```
def edit_member(request, member_id):
    member = get_object_or_404(Member, id=member_id)
    form = MemberForm(request.POST or None, instance=member)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # do something else, like redirect to a different view

    return render(request, 'edit_member.html', {'form': form})
```

If you want to create a new member:

```
    def create_member(request):
        form = MemberForm(request.POST or None)

        if request.method == 'POST':
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                # do something else, like redirect to a different view

        return render(request, 'add_member.html', {'form': form})
```

That's very long-winded as you can actually accomplish both the create and edit action in the same view, but I wanted to demonstrate what was going on in each action.

Unless there's something very specific you need to add to the model from the view, there's no reason to set the model fields by hand from the cleaned data, as the form has already done that after calling `.is_valid()`

Additionally, you'll want to form up your url patterns correctly, as they need to be proper regular expressions:

```
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^profile/$', views.profile, name='profile'),
url(r'^leaderboard/$', views.leaderboard, name='leaderboard'),
url(r'^MemberForm/$', views.Form, name='MemberForm'),
url(r'^MemberUpdate/(?P<member_id>\d+)/$',
    views.MemberUpdate, name='MemberUpdate'),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))
```

and please, use lowercase names for methods, properties and functions and uppercase names for classes in Python.

Finally, you need to update your template code to pass in the `member_id`:

```
{% for member in members %}
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="{% url 'MemberUpdate' member_id=member.id %}">{{ member.name}}</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I've literally done everything you told me and its still not working!! "Reverse for 'MemberUpdate' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['MemberUpdate/(?P<member_id>\\d+)']"

Comment: Can I just ask, what is member_id actually doing? All I want is to display all the members on the webpage and have the feature to edit them

Comment: I've updated my answer, specifically assigning the member_id. You must identify *which* member you want to edit, and passing in the primary key of the member is just one strategy to do so. Otherwise, Django doesn't have the slightest idea on which member you want to edit.

Comment: another approach is to use a ModelFormset, if you wanted to edit them all at once: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: btw, if you haven't already, I would highly suggest going through the Django tutorial, as all of your questions would be answered by working through that: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: For some reason its complaining about my template from the previous tab: "        <li><a href="{% url 'MemberUpdate' %}">Edit Member</a></li>" the message I showed you above! Btw I tried your new version and it still doesnt work

Comment: Works for me. Here's a complete sample app: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5271044/members_app.zip

Comment: You'll need Django 1.7.4 and Python3.4 to run that

Comment: OMG Thank you so much!!!!!!! You've literallt helped me out loads. If I could I'd give you 1000 votes up. Brandon, is there any way of contacting you?

Comment: You're welcome. My contact information is in my profile.

Comment: How would you calculate the average? I dont mean inputting it manually, but I'm sure django can do it for me. Is it possible to get the Wins and Losses into a view, do the calculation for EACH member, and return it to the template? Is this possible?

Comment: I would add that as a property of the `Member` model. If you need to persist it, add it as a `DecimalField`.

Comment: Yes I understand that but how would I do the average calculations for each member?

Comment: It depends on how your models are set up. In the contrived example of the sample app, you can just add a property to the `Member` model to divide the number of wins or losses by the total number of matches. In the real world, you would most likely have a separate model for Matches, or whatever, that records a win or loss between two Members, but you could still use a property to return the average.

Comment: My models are the same as your example that you made. Would it be possible to do it though? I'm sure I can extract the wins and losses, do the calculation, and return them to template?

Comment: Since our comments really don't pertain to the original question, PM me and we can talk about what you need to do further. My email address is in my profile.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start with something like this:

```
member = Member.objects.get(pk=member_id)
```

then

```
form = MemberForm(request.POST, instance=member)
```

Your form will be pre-filled with the member attributes. On POST, changes will be saved.

Comment: is that the only thing I have to change? Because I tried it but its not working

Comment: Well, no, but it's a start. You'll need to pass the `member_id` and stuff. It's in the docs. You'll want to search 'django edit form' or something like that.

Comment: I'm totally confused now @Rob L

Comment: Your form instantiation is incorrect. You can't have a positional argument before a keyword argument. It needs to be: `request = MemberForm(request.POST, instance=member)`

Comment: Sorry, I meant: `form = MemberForm(request.POST, instance=member)`